# angularjs modal initialization using factory

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to make a modal window opening in controller, using app.factory.

Getting strange error and don't understand what the problem.
So, this is the error i got in js console:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=modalServiceProvider%20%3C-%20modalService%20%3C-%20MapController`

Here is my files and structure:

**Main controller:**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'modalService', function($scope, modalService){    
    ///Modal: Add item
    //////////////////
    console.log('dfdfdf');
    $scope.AddItem = modalService.openAddItemDialog($scope);
    }]);
```

open it on simple HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block" ng-click="AddItem()">  </button>
</div>
```

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('modalService', ['$modal', function($modal) {

    function openAddItemDialog($scope) {
        console.log('dfdfdf');
        $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
        $scope.valueToPass = "I must be passed";

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'AddItemDialog.html',
            controller: 'AddItemController',
            resolve: {
                aValue: function () {
                    return $scope.valueToPass;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (paramFromDialog) {
            $scope.paramFromDialog = paramFromDialog;
        });
    }

    return {
        openAddItemDialog: openAddItemDialog
    };
}]);
```

**Modal Controller:**

```
app.controller('AddItemController',function($scope, $modalInstance, aValue) {
    $scope.valuePassed = aValue;
    $scope.close = function () {
        $modalInstance.close("Someone Closed Me");
    };
});
```

**HTML template:**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h2>The title</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    The body of the dialog with the value to pass '{{valuePassed}}'
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

i even don't see the first `console.log('dfdfdf');` func result. so it broke main controller's work in some way.. but blind, can't se, whats the problem? for me, looks like all should work.

** app is defined in separate file like `var app = angular.module('MainPage', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check that you have included the service file in your app page? 

You can find more info about this error [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)

Comment: yes i checked many times now... everything seems to be ok. Thats why asking here. Maybe there is something special about passing `$modal` to factory?